# What sort of dual-locking gate latch will work in my situation?

Tags: lock, gates

Contractor installed  a gate - metal frame with composite “wood” slats - in my backyard. I want to be able to lock and unlock the gate from either side but the contractor is having trouble finding a lock that works, mostly because it seems like it’s not possible to drill the large hole required for a standard lock barrel through the metal post (see pics below)?

I was hoping for a key lock on exterior side and twist knob on interior side but at this point I’m interested in any option that gives me lock/unlock ability on either side. That doesn’t seem like a crazy goal but when I look around at other gates I see lots of non-locking latch closures with a cord thrown over the gate or one-sided locks. I want to enter and exit and be able to lock from either side.

Anybody have a solution?

I saw [this product](https://www.homedepot.com/p/LOKKLATCH-D-D-Black-Two-Sided-Key-Lockable-General-Purpose-Gate-Latch-50110/301638136) but when we went to install it, it turns out the inside lock is really just a child lock kinda thing. Prevents people inside from going out without key but can’t actually lock or open unlock the exterior lock.

Here are pics of gate:

[image: two pics of gate]

Comment: How large of a hole *can* you drill through the gate?

Comment: Please edit the pictures into your question.

Comment: I don't believe in impossible gate lock scenarios. Is the door thickness smaller than the post thickness? Would a surface mounted deadbolt like https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07B58X92C/ work suboptimally because of how the bolt hits the post? What does the other side look like when the gate is shut? Do the faces align over there?

Comment: Just to check we aren't missing something here - does the gate swing or slide shut? (I can't see anything for it to slide in the pictures but it also doesn't make sense that the contractor would say its impossible for a swing shut gate).

Comment: Just search for a pool gate lock.   They are common.  There is a kind with a key and a cable through the gate to a puller inside.  There is a very common kind with a knob on top that you pull upwards, and can be key locked.   Go to a pool and see.

Comment: Please provide dimensions for the post and the metal frame. It looks to me like the frame of the gate might be too thin to accept the bolt of a lock going through it into a hole in the post, but that's just an assumption based on my recently recalibrated Mk I eyeball and what the contractor said.

Comment: Also, this borders on a shopping question (which is off-topic), but I think that @jay613 has a good "general" suggestion of a category of items that might work for you. Maybe he'll make an answer out of his comment...

Comment: Pool locks will probably fit the bill, but if you’re desperate and rich, look at the Lockey Sumo.

Comment: *contractor is having trouble finding a lock that works, mostly because* they don't want to kill their $40 hole saw for an $80 job.

Answer (score 3):

The pool gate lock is the answer.  ( Thanks Jay613)

They are available online and at any pool supply store.

An example is [Pool gate lock](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CK8ZZP9).

Answer (score 2):

What about a mag lock? Looks like you've already got power right there... Would automatically be locked when closed, and there are various access control options for opening with a pin pad, key fob, smartphone, etc.

Basic inexpensive example:

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Waterproof-Systems-Electric-Magnetic-Keychains/dp/B0779PY7QS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0779PY7QS)

Answer (score 1):

Just to contribute the cheapest solution: Drill 1 inch holes in the adjacent panels, get a few feet of plastic-coated chain and a padlock.  Do it near the top so the lock can be reached from either side.   If you get an alpha combo padlock the combination can be "GATE" or "POOL" if you want. :)

It's a nice fence so you probably don't want this relatively ugly solution but it has the advantage, over a pool lock, that when the gate starts to sag a little, or expand/contract, it won't go out of alignment so easily.